# how to load local file into Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have not been able to find a solution to this so will ask the experts.

A co-worker has a .txt file on his laptop that we want to load into Azure SQL DB using SSMS and Bulk Insert.  We can open the local file easily enough but we don't know how to reference this file in FROM clause.

Assuming a file named `myData.txt` is saved to

> c:\Users\Someone

how do we tell Azure SQL DB where that file is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. :) You have to upload a file to an Azure Blob Store and then, from there, you can use BULK INSERT or OPENROWSET to open the file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

I've written an article that describes the steps to open a JSON file here:

https://medium.com/@mauridb/work-with-json-files-with-azure-sql-8946f066ddd4

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this problem by uploading the file to a local database and then use a linked server to my Azure db to insert or update the record. Much easier than creating a Blob Storage. However, if the file is very big or you have a lot of files to upload you might not want to use my method as linked servers is not the quickest connection.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question